# Visual Studio Code Intellisense for C

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense

This is driving me crazy.

Visual Studio Code does Intellisense for stdio.h and windows.h and the other header files that come with Visual Studio. It finds the headers files and Intellisense works despite the directories containing those header files not being in the "includePath" array in the properties json.

However, it's erratic for other header files I have in directories that actually are listed in "includePath".

For some Intellisense knows the function names but does not work for parameters.

For others Intellisense does not even know the function names.

Visual Studio (not Code) does not appear to have these problems.

Where am I confused?

Answer (score 0):

And found the answer: The header files relied on #DEFINEs that were not set. My bad.